# JTAppleCalendar: Is there a way to force update ConfigurationParameters?

Tags: jtapplecalendar

In my current task there is a need to update calendar properties asynchronously.

After I get my calendar update I want to reload calendar collection view (for instance **calendarView** - an entity of JTAppleCalendarView) with the changes just happened to my calendar.

But I found that calling **calendarView.reloadData()** doesn't trigger the delegate's **configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters**.

So is there a proper way of forcing an update of the configuration or the concept of interaction with calendar should be changed? If concept needs to be changed then how is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the ones who may be interested:
In order to force update configuration you may try to reassign **.calendarDataSource** of the JTAppleCalendarView item.
This is for pre 8 version of the calendar.